# Does Azure Active Directory support having a single user tied to multiple profiles, with each profile belonging to its own groups?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My goal is to have the user authenticate with Azure AD and then be presented with a drop-down of profiles they want to access. Based on which profile is selected, the user will have different permissions on the site. I'm trying to avoid a user having to have multiple logins to enforce the different permissions per profile.

Can Azure AD handle this or do I need to tie in custom code in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Users have one identity and can have a set of roles on an app.
Well, just one role unless you have group-based role assignment available :)

This concept sounds like something you will have to build in your app.
Or you will have to have multiple users registered for this one person.